# A Clear and Crescent Danger

Tags: word, knowledge, visual

I was putting up a poster at work the other day when I looked at it and saw this:

[image]

What word was the poster trying to convey?  And for bonus points, where do I work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is

> The logo of the 2021 film [Dune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_%282021_film%29), mirrored horizontally.

So maybe you work

> at a movie theatre, and were putting up the poster on a window?

The title:

> "Clear and *P*resent Danger" is the title of another film (although unrelated to Dune as far as I can tell), hinting at a cinema-themed answer.

Comment: Makes sense to me, btw, rot13(znlor rkcynva gur gvgyr nf jryy?)

Comment: Seems to work, but since they were the one putting up the poster (on the inside of the window, probably), a more succinct answer is possible

Comment: @Bass Ah, of course! For some reason I misread that as "looking up" instead of "putting up". Thanks!

Comment: Fun fact!  Zbivr cbfgref unir n zveeberq irefvba bs gurzfryirf ba gur onpx, gb znxr gur vzntr zber ivoenag jura onpxyvg.